# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'PopoverModule' was called

Tags: angular

I am migrating Angular 4.3 to Angular 8.2 and getting an error:

> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'PopoverModule' was called.
>
> Other information "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",

My code :

```
import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';

imports: [PopoverModule.forRoot()]
```